# How do I check if MD5 hashes of resources are correct in Java game?

Tags: java, resources, md5, verification

I am developing a Java game and I want to verify that the resources are not different from the ones I included. Can I do this by checking the MD5 hash and if I can how?
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you actually try? If so, with what result?

Comment: What do you mean by "resources"? It would be great if you could show what you have done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to get MD5 was found [here](http://www.asjava.com/core-java/java-md5-example/):. I just modified to accept the path to resource and read the bytes of that resource into a byte array which is then passed to the MD5 algorithm

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

    public static String getMD5(String pathToResource) {
            Path path = Paths.get(pathToResource);
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            try {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(data);
                BigInteger number = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);
                String hashtext = number.toString(16);
                // Now we need to zero pad it if you actually want the full 32 chars.
                while (hashtext.length() < 32) {
                    hashtext = "0" + hashtext;
                }
                return hashtext;
            }
            catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am talking about .png resources and things like that

Comment: Ok then you need to modify this function to take in a byte[] array and pass that to md.digest().  I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Hello, I have this method :  public static void verifyFiles() throws Exception {
  floorHash = MD5.getMD5("res/textures/floor.png");
  System.out.println(floorHash);
  if (floorHash != "51392ec73d3ffac5a7ed3bd024bf07ab") {
   System.out.println(
     "There is a problem in your game installation. Please restart/reinstall, and if the problem persists please contact support.");
  } else {

  }

Comment: And it does what is in the if statement all the time even though the md5 of the floor.png is correct

Comment: Don't compare strings using == or! =       use the equals() method of the String class